# Array, which elements links to elements of another array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-address

I want to have an array each elements of each somehow indicates some element of another resizable array
I tried:

```
vector <int> a={1,2,3};
vector <int*> b={*(a[0]),*(a[1]),*(a[2]));
```

But every editing of size of vector a, copies himself to empty place of memory, so pointers in array b links to an empty place

Comment: I understand your problem (I think), but does that code even compile?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of elements in advance? If so then simply [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) sufficient space to avoid re-allocations.

Comment: You can try `&` instead of `*` to take the address of the elements in `a`. But you'll need to avoid reallocs of `a` anyway (e.g. with `reserve` as noted above).

Comment: In contrast a `std::list` is much slower in most situations but pointers to elements into don't get invalidated – so that might be an alternative...

Comment: Store indices instead of pointers.

Comment: `*` instead of `&` might have been a simple accident on creating the [mre] – which shows that you should always *compile* even the most simple code to avoid creating red herrings that have nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: Or instead of pointers store indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used unordered_map to store elements. In second array I stored keys to map.
How to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution solve your problem? You can access to `a` address indices through `b`. Be sure of the integrity of `a` when you interact with `b`.

```cpp
std::vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int>& b{ a };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> vect{1,2,3};
int *ptr=&vect[0];
cout<<*ptr<<*(ptr+1)<<*(ptr+2)<<endl;
```

Here, I have created pointer `ptr` that will point to first element of `vect` vector. Then from `ptr` pointer we get access of all elements one by one.
Does this solve your problem?